# Why $\mu_3 = \operatorname{ diag} (\zeta_3, \zeta_3)$ is the kernel of the G'-action?

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, group-actions, roots-of-unity

Here is the paper I am trying to understand:

> [image]

But I do not understand why  $\mu_3 = \operatorname{ diag} (\zeta_3, \zeta_3)$ is the kernel of the G'-action? could anyone show me the details of the calculations please?

Comment: [Images of text and mathematical expressions are discouraged here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320052/why-are-images-of-text-code-and-mathematical-expressions-discouraged). Please do not rely on an image for the bulk of your question.

Comment: So Sorry about that I will edit my question within 4-5 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $g = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix} \in G'$ is in the kernel of the action. Then
$$p((ax+by, cx+dy)) = p(g(x,y)) = (g^{-1} \cdot p)((x,y)) = p((x,y))$$
for all $p \in \operatorname{Sym}^3(\mathbb{C}^2)$ and all $(x,y) \in \mathbb{C}^2$.

In particular, this holds for $p((x,y)) = x^3$ at the point $(x,y) = (1,0)$, yielding $a^3 = 1$.

Next, this holds for $p((x,y)) = x^3$ at the point $(x,y) = (0,1)$, yielding
$b^3 = 0$ (so $b = 0$).

Likewise, using $p((x,y)) = y^3$ and $(x,y) = (1,0)$ we get $c^3 = 0$ (so $c = 0$).

Finally, using $p((x,y)) = x^2y$ and $(x,y) = (1,1)$ we get $a^2 d = 1$, so multiplying by $a$ on both sides yields $d = a$.

We now know that $g$ is a scalar matrix such that $g^3$ is the identity. The set of all such matrices is generated by $\operatorname{diag}(\zeta_3, \zeta_3)$. Conversely, the above analysis shows that all such matrices are in the kernel of the action.

I have one small nit to pick with your text: the kernel $\mu_3$ is *generated* by the diagonal matrix $\operatorname{diag}(\zeta_3, \zeta_3)$, but of course it also contains the identity matrix and $\operatorname{diag}(\zeta_3^2, \zeta_3^2)$.

Comment: So you mean that this is just the generator of the kernel and not just the kernel, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}(2)$ generated by $\operatorname{diag}(\zeta_3, \zeta_3)$ is $\mu_3$.

Comment: I think you meant at the end of the third line $\mathbb C^2$ not $\mathbb C^3,$ right?

Comment: So, may be in our case here the notation $\operatorname{diag} (\zeta_3, \zeta_3)$ does not have the usual meaning. right?

Comment: As far as I understand the meaning of  $\operatorname{diag} (\zeta_3, \zeta_3)$  is the diagonal $2\times 2$ matrix with $\zeta_3$ along the diagonals, right?

Comment: I am not quite sure why $\operatorname{diag}(\zeta_3^2, \zeta_3^2)$ should be in the kernel. Could you please explain this?

Comment: But I can see also that from $p((x,y)) = y^3$ at the point $(0,1)$ we will have that $d^3 = 1$ i.e., $d=1.$ right?

Comment: Are you using the idea that $a^3 = 1$ does not imply that $a=1,$ .... I do not think so, I think I am saying nonsense ..... right?

Comment: Yes I meant $\mathbb{C}^2$, thanks! And indeed (in the complex numbers), $a^3 = 1$ does not imply $a = 1$, since also $\zeta_3^3 = 1$ and $(\zeta_3^2)^3 = 1$. To check that $\operatorname{diag}(\zeta_3, \zeta_3)$ is in the kernel we simply verify the equation $p((\zeta_3 x, \zeta_3 y)) = p((x,y))$ for all $p \in \operatorname{Sym}^3(\mathbb{C})$. This holds because these polynomials are homogeneous of degree $3$.

Comment: Once we know that $s = \operatorname{diag}(\zeta_3, \zeta_3)$ is in the kernel, then the subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}(2)$ generated by $s$ must be a subset of the kernel (because the kernel is a subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}(2)$). The subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}(2)$ generated by $s$ is called $\mu_3$, and it has three elements: the identity, $s$, and $s^2 = \operatorname{diag}(\zeta_3^2, \zeta_3^2)$.